# How to specify package installation order in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, numpy, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

Using `pyproject.toml`, I'm trying to install a specific dependency (`lap==0.4.0`).

As per the project's [setup.py](https://github.com/gatagat/lap/blob/master/setup.py) script, it requires `numpy`.

This is fine. But it's also problematic for me because, despite `numpy` being defined higher than `lap` under my `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`, I'm consistently met with the error that `ImportError: lap requires numpy, please "pip install numpy".`

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.8"
numpy = "^1.22.0"
...
lap = "==0.4.0"
```

There's a thread [here](https://github.com/gatagat/lap/issues/38) that discusses why the project's approach to checking for numpy is problematic, but falls short of offering a solution for resolving this using `pyproject.toml`.

How might I solve this? Is there a way to guarantee `numpy` is installed *prior* to attempting to install `lap`?

The linked thread suggests it may also be a pip issue, i.e. they state installation "*succeeds with pip 20.0.2, but for pip 22.0.3 fails*".

Comment: "_How to specify package installation order in pyproject.toml?_" Not possible. -- Maintainers of `lap` should provide a `pyproject.toml` with `numpy` as "build dependency". But if I remember correctly depending on `numpy` is complex anyway and hard to solve neatly.

Comment: There must be some workaround here

Comment: The workaround is to have an installation script that will, for example, do `pip install numpy && poetry install`

Comment: @deepspace in the actual context exposed in the question that would not work, or only with old _pip_ maybe.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to execute `pip install numpy`, specified within pyproject.toml`, prior to installing the remaining dependencies?

Comment: No. The thing is, with newest pip versions, each "build" is done in a new, fresh, clean, empty virtual environment and build dependencies are installed in that build environment before building. `lap` seems to have `numpy` as build dependency but does not declare it, so pip can not do the right thing. -- So `lap` is the "culprit" here, by not doing its packaging properly. -- The other thing is that `lap` should publish "wheels" (not just sdist), so that it would be possible to install `lap` without having to build anything locally (wheels are already "built"/"compiled").

Comment: Fork and fix `lap` ?

Comment: If I were you, I think I would build a "wheel" of `lap` for myself, locally. This is possible with the right `pip` commands and options (maybe `pip install numpy && pip install --no-build-isolation lap`). Then I would try to put this wheel in Poetry's collection of built artifacts, or I would put it in a private, local package index server. -- Or yes, fork and fix lap, or fix and contribute the fix to lap directly.

Comment: Agree that `lap` is the culprit here; a totally sub-par approach the author adopted for build deps. @Keldorn, thankfully for this specific case, it appears someone has indeed forked the library for this exact case...! (`lap05==0.5.1`). Thank you @sinorac for the suggested workaround also

Comment: To be fair, `lap` seems to have not seen a release since 2018, long before all these new improvements in the Python packaging ecosystem, long before _pip_ switched to "build isolation", long before "build dependencies" were standardized, so it is not fair (of me) to "blame" them as "culprit". -- Indeed, seems like the `lap05` fork can unblock the situation for you here. Good luck!